# IIS Express Debug Mode Issue

Tags: c#, iis, webserver, port

There is an issue when I debugging my backend net5.0 project. The issue is "Web server failed to listen on port 5001" then I changed port but the problem does not change.

[image]

Comment: Port number could be blocked by a virus checker or another application is using the port.

Comment: Have you checked if the port is currently in use? Try a `netstat -ab` to check.

Comment: Might be a silly question and I don't know if your dev environment allows it, but have you set your DEV SSL port and HTTP port to the same port? i.e. 5001?

Comment: @Tomás I checked but it is not in use.

Comment: `{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "Gateway.Command": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
      }
    }
  }
}
`
this is my launchSettings.json

Comment: port can be used from antoher project when I debugged.

Comment: when I changed my port also getting same error.
`waiting for the web server to listen on port 53855` and then same result
`web server failed to listen on port 53855`

Comment: I think issue is changed. Actually not changed. we identified the problem that is wrong with net5.0. I can debug my project with net3.1 and net6.0 but net5.0 is not working. I installed .net5.0 sdk and I used to VS Community 2022 then I changed to VS Enterprise 2022 maybe issue caused by this.

Comment: It's just waste of time to continue any investigation on .NET 5, as it reached end of life a while ago. VS2022 is known to stop supporting end-of-life technologies.

Comment: Try opening VS as administrator, I believe internal communication between .net architecture and IIS.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue after loading one of the existing project.
I was able to resolve this by installing the .NET version project was targetting. (In my case, it was .NET 5).

Reason for the error: Since .NET's previous versions are out-of-support, Visual Studio won't install previous versions during installation.

Remedy: Intall SDK by yourself after installing Visual Studio

Comment: Since Visual Studio 2019 updating it has become a nightmare, updates have failed every single time and it gives cryptic error messages which are hard to understand and fix. I uninstalled Visual Studio 2019(which supports .NET 5) and installed Visual Studio 2022(which doesn't support .NET 5) and tried to run a .NET 5 project and got this error "Process with an id of ### is not running" and then "Web server failed to listen on port". Why could it not give a simple understandable error saying, "The project is targeting .NET 5 which is unsupported. Try upgrading to .NET 6."? This is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case that was

```
app.Run();
```

line deleted accidently from Program.cs

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that i added some configuration to the appsettings.json file and i forgot to add a comma. fixing that and everything was back to work.

Comment: what is some configuration?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using application url with port and you are using different url port in the environment variables settings in some field like origin. Then this problem arises. You have to keep them same.

Comment: Actually I can debug another project. There is no problem. But this one does not work. It happens suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Issue after updating my packages, to fix it:

Make sure that the DotNet version in the csproj is the same as the version found in the following folders:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

So my `csproj` was contained:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

So I made sure that all the File locations specified above the csproj file had versions 7.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this seemed to be caused by the random signing out of my Microsoft Account in Visual Studio 2022. As soon as I re-entered my creds, it went away.